# Use grep to execute aws ecs 'execute' command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I would like to connect to my containers with aws ecs execute container command

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster <cluster> --task <task_id> --container <container_name> --interactive --command "/bin/bash"
```

Currently I need to go to my aws dashboard and grab the task id but recently I realized I could just use

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster> --family <container> | grep -e "arn"
```

** Note I still need to grab the actual id from the result

I would like to run the second one and use the output to call the first one

I have tried:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster>--family <family> | grep -e "arn" | aws ecs execute-command --cluster <cluster> --task $1 --container <container> --interactive --command "/bin/bash"
```

and

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster <cluster>--task $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster> --family <task-family> | grep -e \"arn\" | awk '{print $1}')  --container <container-name> --interactive --command "/bin/bash"
```

any ideas ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use jq to parse the result instead of grep. For example:

1. List available tasks in your cluster, returns a json response:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "$cluster" --region "$region"
```

2. Extract the first task arn using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
jq -r .taskArns[0]
```

3. Run `execute-command`, using xargs to take the pipeline output as an arg:

```
xargs aws ecs execute-command --cluster "$cluster" --region "$region" --container "$container" --command "/bin/bash" --interactive --task
```

All together:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "$cluster" --region "$region" | \
  jq -r .taskArns[0] | \
  xargs aws ecs execute-command --cluster "$cluster" --region "$region" --container "$container" --command "/bin/bash" --interactive --task
```

I would recommend putting this into a bash script for ease of use, but if you want a one-line script this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but it worked

```
alias connect-to-app="aws ecs execute-command --cluster <cluster> --task \"$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster> --family <family> | grep -e "arn" | grep -o '/<cluster>/\w*' | sed "s@/<cluster>/@@g")\" --container <container> --interactive --command \"/bin/bash"\"
```